# Inserting images into java code editor

Tags: java, image, parsing, math, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse to write math related programs.

I want to make code more understandable, especially math code, using images representing my math code in for example LaTex formulas.

I know how to translate my math code into MathML and then into picture, so the main problem is inserting images.

Hope for answers.

Comment: Do you really want that images in your editor? For a PDF output, http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/ would be an ideal solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can't insert images (except for ascii-art! ;) in the Java source code.

You *can* however write [JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) which includes images simply by providing an `<img />` tag.

Btw, you should know that Java allows unicode in it's source code, so it's perfectly legal to write ∫, ∑, Π, α, Δ, δ, π, ε, Θ, θ etc directly in your source code (even though I'm not sure I would recommend it.)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a way to insert images directly into source code files. In fact, I would be extremely surprised if there is.

Generally speaking, depending on the complexity of the formulas involved, you might be able to get away with one of the following work-arounds:

1. Use the characters included in the Unicode math symbols areas, and write the formulas straight up in a comment.
2. Include a LaTeX or similar expression in a comment. Don't do this unless your fellow developers are at least reasonably familiar with the LaTeX syntax, though.
3. Include a text reference to an external document or image file.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc system supports ['taglet'](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) plug-ins, so I would use a suitable tag which takes latex and creates images in the HTML  and include the latex in the source. If the other devs don't understand the latex, they can always look at the JavaDocs.

http://www.ohloh.net/p/latextaglet may be suitable, but I've not used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I just responded to another of your questions, where I attached a project that shows you exactly how to do this:

[How to enlarge eclipse java editor functionality using plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017862/how-to-enlarge-eclipse-java-editor-functionality-using-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, we've just started investigating the source.